# Assembly MASM procedure not running

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to display the sum and difference of 2 signed integer in the middle of the console. I've used the Irvine library to help with some of the functions such as clear screen. In addition, i've encountered 2 problems.

1) displaySum procedure not running

2) The msg display disappears after it runs

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
        INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


    .data

    msg1 byte "Input signed interger1: ", 0
    msg2 byte "Input signed integer2: ", 0
    msgSum byte "Sum: ", 0
    msgDiff byte "Difference: ", 0
    msgWait byte "Press any key...", 0
    var1 SDWORD ?
    var2 SDWORD ?



    .code
    main proc

    mov ecx, 3

    l1:
    call ClrScr
    call locate
    call input
    call displaySum
    call displayDiff
    call waitForKey

    loop l1;






    exit
    main endp
    ; clear screen and locate cursor
locate proc
        ;sub edx,edx

        mov   dh,10 ; row 10
        mov   dl,20 ; column 20
        call  Gotoxy; locate cursor
        ret
    locate endp

displaySum proc
    call locate
    mov eax, var1
    add eax, var2
    mov edx, OFFSET msgSum
    call writeString
    call writeInt
    call crlf

        ret
        displaySum endp

displayDiff proc
    call locate
    mov eax, var1
    sub eax, var2
    mov edx, OFFSET msgDiff
    call writeString
    call writeInt

        ret
        displayDiff endp

input proc

    mov edx, OFFSET msg1
    call writeString
    call readInt
    mov var1, eax
    call crlf

    call locate
    mov edx, OFFSET msg2
    call writeString
    call readInt
    mov var2, eax

    ret
    input endp

waitForKey proc
    call locate
    mov  edx, OFFSET msgWait
    call WriteString
    call readChar

    ret
    waitForKey endp

    end main
```

Comment: _"displaySum procedure not running"_ How do you know? And why do all your functions clear the screen and output to the same position on the screen? What's the point of calling `displaySum` if `displayDiff` will erase its output immediately after?

Comment: "displaySum procedure not running" How do you know? 
-It doesn't display on console the message
What's the point of calling displaySum if displayDiff will erase its output immediately after?
-I wasn't aware of wiping its output immediately, you refer to clear screen? I thought that was to clear the screen only

Comment: If one function writes something to the screen, and then the next function comes along and clears the screen, how do you expect to see what the first function wrote?

Comment: @Michael the 2nd integer input statement is overlapping the 1st integer input statement and this happens for the rest of the waitforkey procedure as well. The sum and diff is not showing for some reason. Btw I moved the clear screen from the locate procedure to the loop

Comment: Single-step it with the debugger to see how your code executes.  Looking at what it prints on screen is only an indirect view of what's happening; get the real picture with a debugger.